# in-app purchase validation on single device but multiple application users

Tags: cordova, validation, in-app-purchase, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am building a subscription based cordova/phonegap mobile application but I think this issue exists with the native apps also.

For reference there has been some discussions and a partial solution about this issue here but it doesn't solve the problem completly:

[in-app purchase validation - validate purchase as per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788204/in-app-purchase-validation-validate-purchase-as-per-user/40030276#40030276)

The issue is let's say user A register/login to the app and makes a renewable subscription based purchase. A receipt is returned and I am verifying it on my server side and everything is good. Now User A logs out of the app and registers/logs in as a new user B. The same receipt is retrieved for user B because in app purchases belong to the apple id of the user and A and B both are using the same Apple id. The partial solution that is offered in the other post and I have already implemented is that to store all the receipt verification along with their application user id on the server side and each time IAP loads check the user id associated with the original_transaction_id which is provided in the receipt and reject the service to user B.

This works but only prevents user B from accessing the paid features. What if user B also wants to subscribe? When I try to purchase by user B, Apple is responding that you already have a valid subscription. Apple doesn't know anything about my application users, since it is from the same Apple id it thinks it is already subscribed. So user B is stuck, he can't subscribe and he can't use the user A's subscribed features.

Is there a way to differentiate the purchases/receipts per application user or some how solve this problem?

Thanks